# Як правильно формуюча чи формувальна обрізка дерева?

Tags: правопис

[Обрізка](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D1%96%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0) дерева для надання форми крони, як правильно написати "формуюча" чи "формувальна" обрізка дерев? В описах рослин зустрічають обидва варіанти.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аналогічно з рятувальний мало б бути *формувальна*. Бо таке обрізання призначене для формування крони.

З Є. Д. ЧАК - «Складні випадки українського слововживання»:

> Слово *рятувальний* означає «спеціально створений для рятування», «призначений для рятування». «З’явився над морем літак, сипнув на воду два *рятувальних* круги і полетів у напрямі берега» (А. Шиян). «*Рятувальна* експедиція вдруге вивозила людей» (М. Трублаїні).